# Deploying react app with nestjs server on cloud service for better SEO

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, seo, nestjs

I am aware that my topic is already has many answers, but I can not find what I need and want to listen to cutting edge trend.
I am building react application with create-react-app and nestjs as backend server. After deployment I found out that there is some trouble with SEO on my website and I thought my app deploying structure might be wrong. 
Here is my structure.

1. S3 for react app hosting.
2. Cloudfront
3. Nestjs server on EC2
4. RDS for database
5. Route53

So my react app website url is https://myapp.com, server url is https://server.myapp.com. I call server apis on client by using axios with server url like https://server.myapp.com/v1/users.
I found out many people deploy there both client and server in one EC2 instance using tools like NGINX or APACHE. The reason I was not adopting these were the benefit of using cloud services was I do not have to concern about these. But after deploying applications, it seems deploying on same instance is more better is many ways.
Can I listen to some ways of structuring web app deployment with server? And is my structure is the reason of poor SEO?

Answer (score 1):

It's upon to you how you want to deeply and host your frontend and backend whether on the same instance or different instances it's according to your apps traffic and whole other factors.

Now we come upon the SEO part. In your case, the first SEO factor will be the content that you are serving on the internet and another factor will be the performance of your website. The content part totally depends upon you that how you are designing it or writing the content. But there are some strategies I can share on increasing your performance so that this factor doesn't create any chaos for you.

Since your content generation is dynamic and it will generate when the user requests a particular resource from your server. So caching can help you here to optimize the initial server response time. So you can cache your content by using Nginx, varnish, or use a service like Cloudflare.